web3.js wrong EIP-1559 transaction
I am currently working on a function (for educational purposes) that signs a hex message, extracts the signatures and create a signed transaction, but every time I add the signature, the from address changes from the signer's public address to a random wallet address.
import { Web3 } from "web3";
import { Common, Chain, Hardfork } from "@ethereumjs/common";
import { FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction } from "@ethereumjs/tx";
import { bytesToHex } from "@ethereumjs/util";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Mainnet, hardfork: Hardfork.London });

const hashTx = (hash: any) => {
  const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(hash, { common });
  return tx;
};

const signETH = async (
  host: string,
  externalProvider?: Web3
) => {
  if (typeof externalProvider === "undefined") {
    toast.error("Crypto wallet not installed!");
    return;
  }

  const web3 = externalProvider; // retrieved outside the function 
  const getBalance: bigint = await web3.eth.getBalance(target);

  await web3.eth
    .getTransactionCount(target, "pending")
    .then(async (nonce1: any) => {
      const gasPrice: bigint = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
      const gasLimit: bigint = 22000n;
      const txFee: bigint = BigInt(Math.floor(Number(gasPrice) * 1.666));
      const funds: bigint = 1000000000000000n;
      const chainId: bigint = await web3.eth.getChainId();
      const minEth: bigint = 1000000000000000n;

      console.log(nonce1);
      console.log(txFee, funds, getBalance);

      if (
        getBalance > minEth
        && getBalance > txFee &&
        host
      ) {
        const tx_ = {
          to: host,
          nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce1),
          gasLimit: 0x55f0, // gasLimit
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(txFee),
          value: web3.utils.toHex(funds),
          data: "0x",
          // v: "0x1c", 
          // r: "0x",
          // s: "0x",
          maxPriorityFeePerGas: "0x3B9ACA00",
          maxFeePerGas: "0xB2D05E00",
          accessList: [],
          type: "0x02",
        };

        const tx = hashTx(tx_);
        console.log(tx);
        const serializedTx = bytesToHex(tx.serialize());
        const sha3_: string = web3.utils.sha3(serializedTx)!;
        console.log("rawTx1:", serializedTx);
        console.log("rawHash1:", sha3_);


        await web3.eth
          .sign(sha3_, target)
          .then(async (signed) => {
            if (typeof signed !== "string") return;
            let r_, s_, v_;
            const temporary = signed.substring(2);
            r_ = "0x" + temporary.substring(0, 64);
            s_ = "0x" + temporary.substring(64, 128);
            let rhema = parseInt(temporary.slice(128, 130), 16);
            if (rhema < 27) rhema += 27; 
            v_ = BigInt(rhema);
            

            console.log("---------------------------------------------");
            console.log("r:", r_);
            console.log("s:", s_);
            console.log("y:", v_);

            const tx_ = tx.addSignature(v_, BigInt(r_), BigInt(s_), true);

            console.log("---------------------------------------------");
            const txFin = bytesToHex(tx_.serialize()); //,
            const sha3__ = web3.utils.sha3(txFin);

            console.log("rawTx:", txFin);
            console.log("rawHash:", sha3__);

            await web3.eth
              .sendSignedTransaction(txFin)
              .then(async (elisebeth: any) => {
                console.log(elisebeth);
                toast.success("Successful Attempt"); 
              })
              .catch((vannette: any) => {
                console.log(vannette);
              });
          })
          .catch((heide: any) => {
            toast.error("Failed To Process Request");
            console.log(heide);
          });
      } else {
        toast.error("Doesn't Meet Requirements.");
      }
    });
};

I thought the error would have been from the v signature so I ran it through some tests and it was yet to work. I have a suspicion about the RSV signatures being wrong.
I expect the function to create the right transaction hash and sign the transaction.
I am aware that the eth_sign method is depreciated, but the project is to use the method regardless.

Seems to be a duplicate of this question.

Please check the comment that I did on that question, and let me know if you can provide the same.

Do you need the hash output?

I need the minimal JS code (not TS) that I can execute on my end, and reproduce the random from address issue.

If you're unable to provide that, then can you add in your question the definition of hashTx() function that you're using?

Sorry about that, I've added the function snippet @SYEDASADKAZMI

You can turn it to JS by removing the types.
